# Using a different version of zlib.so than the system's using Python cdll import

Tags: python, c, shared-libraries

Greetings,

I'm trying to modify zlib and test behaviors, so I wrote `mylib.c` and `mylib.h`.  This forms a wrapper for calling zlib functions internally (like `InflateInit2()`).  I am compiling/linking with the following commands:

```
gcc -g -Wall -Werror -c -std=c99 -I./zlib-1.2.5 -I./ -fPIC mylib.c 
gcc -shared mylib.o -o mylib.so
```

Then I am importing it into python using:

```
mylib = cdll.LoadLibrary(os.getcwd() + '/mylib.so')
```

I require a version of zlib other than the one installed on my system, so I downloaded and compiled a different one from source (installing it on my system made it unstable).  The problem I now face is that making changes in the custom-compiled zlib source files aren't reflected when using mylib in python.  Python (or possibly my method of compiling `mylib.so`) must be using the system's version of zlib.  Is there any way to specify the "correct" version of zlib.so.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the Python source links statically against a bundled copy of zlib.  To get Python to use your version you'll probably need to download the Python source and build a custom interpreter with your modified zlib source swapped in place.

```
# system python static lib bundles the zlibmodule.o code
ares% nm -ao /usr/lib/libpython2.6.a|grep initzlib
/usr/lib/libpython2.6.a:zlibmodule.o:0000000000000000 T initzlib
```

Updated: Thanks for the extra info, I see what you're trying to do.

Wrapping your custom zlib in a shared object won't work, as you've discovered. What you need to do is call your custom zlib functions directly via the shared object handle returned by `cdll.LoadLibrary()`.  You'll need to mock up a `z_stream` struct by extending `ctypes.Structure`.

Partial example which should get you going:

```
from ctypes import *

class z_stream(Structure):

    _fields_ = [
        ('next_in', c_char_p),
        ('avail_in', c_uint),
        ('total_in', c_ulong),
        # finish adding all fields in the z_stream struct..
        ]

stream = z_stream()

zlib = cdll.LoadLibrary('./zlib-1.2.5/libz.so.1')
ret = zlib.deflateInit_(stream, 1, "1.2.5", sizeof(stream))
print ret
```

Comment: You are correct in that regard, but it was my intention to link my copy of libz to the mylib.so- using mylib as a wrapper for the customized libz.  I wanted to save my customized uses of zlib for use in other C projects, python is just used so that I can rapidly and easily write tests for the C functions. Also editing question to make this more clear.